# Equivalence of ideals of holomorophic functions seen as real smooth

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ideals, complex-geometry, algebraic-curves

Given two (radical, prime) ideals $I_1$ and $I_2$ of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}^2,0}$ generated by holomorphic functions in two variables $g_1(z_1,z_2)$ and $g_2(z_1,z_2)$ (resp.), one can also consider the ideals
$$ I_i^\mathbb{R}=(\mathcal{Re}\ g_i, \mathcal{Im}\ g_i)\subset \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{R}^4,0}\ \ \ \ , i=1,2.$$

**Question:** $\psi^*I_1^\mathbb{R}=I_2^\mathbb{R}$ for some smooth diffeomorphism of $\mathbb{R}^4$ (real analytic if necessary) implies that $\phi^*I_1=I_2$ for some complex isomorphism $\phi$ of $\mathbb{C}^2$.

**My vague idea:**
I tried with
$$ \mathcal{Re}\ g_1= \mathcal{Re}\ g_2\ h_{RR} + \mathcal{Im}\ g_2 \ h_{RI}$$
$$\mathcal{Im}\ g_1 = \mathcal{Re}\ g_2\ h_{IR} + \mathcal{Im}\ g_2 \ h_{II}$$
and use Cauchy Riemann equations to solve this.

Comment: What is $\mathcal O_{\mathbb R^4, 0}$? The ring containing all germs of $C^\infty$-functions? Or analytic functions only?

Comment: @red_trumpet For the complex setting the ring is the holomorphic functions on two variables, and $I_i$ are ideals inside that ring. For the real setting the ring is the $C^\infty$ (real smooth) functions of 4 variables, and $I_i^\mathbb{R}$ are ideals inside this other ring generated as shown above. The question is if isomorphism in the real implies isomorphism in the complex.